# Translation of Stange's (1971) approach to tolerance limits in simple linear regression

Tags: regression, references, tolerance-interval

In Stange (1971), Angewandte Statistik, Vol. II. Springer Verlag, Berlin, Heidelberg,
New York, 141-143, the author derives a tolerance limit for simple linear regression which is widely used in finding withholding periods for food safety standards. Unfortunately (for me) the text is in German and the mathematical nomenclature is rather unusual. I've tried employing Google Translate with the assistance of a German friend but to no avail. Does anyone know of a derivation in English please?
For your information, Stange's tolerance limit approach is based on finding a statistic whose lower quantile of a given probability corresponds to a selected upper quantile of the conditional distribution of the variable of interest. Its advantage is that its tolerance limit  uses the standard normal distribution versus the non-central t-distribution employed in the classical tolerance limit formula.